# Shower head arm rusted through

Tags: plumbing, concrete, shower

My showerhead arm is rusted through and water is leaking out everywhere. The tube and its thread is through a concrete wall. I have no idea how to repair. I know I'll have to break through the concrete, but not sure if doing so well break the water tube beneath.

[image: Shower head tube rust]

Any recommendations before I have to call a plumber?

Update:

I decided to cut through the cement around with a cold chisel to free from the cement a bit. 
[image: shower head around cement]

Comment: This probably isn't concrete. It's plaster. In either case it can be repaired, but you shouldn't need to damage it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can fix this *without* having to damage the wall. This is a common problem, and there are inexpensive [tools designed to remove any pieces of the shower arm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDppaI1RbHc) left inside the wall in the fitting.

You might be able to borrow one, but [similar tools can be bought for less than US$10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K3Y8CXO). Check your local hardware store or plumbing supply store.

- Unscrew the shower head. A piece of rubberized shelf liner or [jar gripper](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00F67TLFC) is useful to protect your hand and provide a high-friction grip on the fitting, but pliers can be used, at the risk of damaging the shower head.
- Using the rubber gripper, again, turn the shower arm counter-clockwise to remove it. It may break off, or pieces of the thread may remain in the female fitting, and this is where the internal pipe extractor is useful. **Be gentle,** since you do *not* want to damage the fitting in the wall.
- Replacement shower arms are no more expensive than the extractor, and are common hardware-store items. Measure the depth of the hole, and bring in fragments of the shower arm to get the correct size part. A good brass fitting should last many years.

BTW, I've removed pieces of a brass fitting with just a flat screwdriver, inserted at an angle -- but the old fitting was in *much* better shape than that in the photo.

Comment: I have a replacement showe arm. Didn't know about the extractor tool. Thanks!! Will try to find it. My main worry is that I don't know how deep into the wall the thread is. Tried moving it once before all the rust, but wouldn't budge.